# Why I get different Total, but same values?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I needed to replace this measure:

```
CALCULATE([GM % YTD], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
```

By this one:

```
VAR VAR1 = ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES(Revenue[Key_Client]), 
                       "Col1", CALCULATE([GM % YTD], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]),
                        REMOVEFILTERS(Revenue[Type],Revenue[SectorType]))
)

RETURN AVERAGEX(VAR1, [Col1])
```

Both measures point to **GM % YTD**, which is:

```
CALCULATE([GM %], DATESYTD('Date'[Date],"31/05"))
```

I get this, when I display them side by side:

[image]

The values are ok, my problem is with the **Total**. I am unable to find how/where is the aggregation on the left column done... How is that  73,2% achieved? It doesn't seem to be average...

Also… how can I force the measure on the right to do the same aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

In the ADDCOLUMNS version, you are iterating over each `Revenue[Key_Client]` and only averaging after the `[GM % YTD]` has been calculated for each one separately. For a single client, there's only one thing to average, so the value isn't affected by that step.

Generally, you want to compute the measure over all clients together rather than averaging the individual numbers together to get a standard weighted average rather than an average where all clients are weighted equally.